# What does if(x) exactly resolve to in C?

Tags: c, if-statement, standards

Doing stuff like

```
int x = 3;
if(x)
```

is quite common thing to do in C, but what does exactly if(x) resolve to according to the standard?

Is it equivalent to if(x == 1) or if(x != 0) or something else?

Comment: In your context, non-zero value of `x` would imply `true`.

Comment: Is there some reason why you're asking us rather than **reading the standard**?  Why are you asking other people to read the standard for you?

Comment: if (x) is equal to if (x != 0) if that helps.

Comment: @EricLippert You can't expect anybody to read a standard that is 900 pages long and super expensive.

Comment: @FUZxxl: The original poster expects other people to do just that.

Comment: I don't expect people to read it /again/ or something. I just expect them to either know it better than I do or just look up the relevant section inside it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the C99 standard section *6.8.4.1 The if statement*:

> In both forms, **the first substatement is executed if the expression compares unequal to 0**. In the else form, the second substatement is executed if the expression compares equal to 0. If the first substatement is reached via a label, the second substatement is not executed.

Meaning `if (x)` is equivalent to `if (x != 0)`.

---

The *forms* in the quoted section is referring to:

```
 selection-statement:
     if ( expression ) statement
     if ( expression ) statement else statement
     switch ( expression ) statement
```

Comment: I guess that _forms_ does not refer to the `switch` line in this context.

Comment: @Virgile, no. There is a section just after that refers to the `switch`.

Comment: But in the paragraph you quoted, _forms_ can only be one of the two `if` lines.

Comment: @Virgile, the quoted paragraph is from _The if statement_ section, so the _both forms_ matches the `_if_` forms of a selection statement. There is a _The switch statement_ section that matches the third selection form.

Answer (score 2):

This would resolve to something like

```
if (x!=0)
```

You can pretty much put anything in the `if` clause in C. Another valid example would be:

```
if(x=5)
```

The result of this operation would be setting `x` to 5 and entering the body of the if. Here, if you set the value of `x` to 0, then the `if` would fail (will be false).

My advice is to always use boolean expression, despite that you can use this kind of syntax.

Answer (score 0):

It is condition for if as in boolean type, that means

```
if x is true
```

and it is true when it is not equal to 0, which resolves to

```
if (x!=0)
```

**C considers any non-zero value true and any zero value false**

Answer (score 0):

Here is what is written from your C book: The C Programming Language, by Kernighan and Ritchie in section 3.1 on if-else statements:

> The if-else statement is used to express decisions. Formally the syntax is
>
> if (*expression*)
>
> *statement1*
>
> else
> *statement2*
>
> where the else part is optional. The *expression* is evaluated; **if it is true (that is, if *expression* has a non-zero value)**, statement1 is executed. If it is false (*expression* is zero) and if there is an else part, *statement2* is executed instead.